# Was there an attempt to create a programming language aimed for maximal abstraction?

Tags: terminology, syntax, abstract-data-types, computer-vs-human, robotics

I am trying to understand if a programming language can have totally or almost totally the abstraction level shared between generally all human languages so that it would allow a human to code a machine, or to communicate with a machine, similarly to how this person would communicate with a human and in general the machine will reply adequately (say, solving a problem for that person).

### Possible pseudocode:

`hello`;

`in plea`, [open shop] `at (time)` (06:00) `and` [in such day]:
`since` (06:00) `until` (08:00) [sort stuff],
`since` (08:00) `until` (20:00) [accept customers];

`in plea`, `if` [no visitor or animal is in shop] `than` [turn off air condition)],
`else`, [turn on air condition];

`in plea`, `if` [a customer finished shopping and payed everything] `than` [tell generally every customer the message {{thank you for buying at our store}}];

`also`
`in plea`, `if` [no visitor or animal is in shop], `than` `since` (20:00) `until` (08:00) [close shop], `else` [ask the being to exit and if it doesn't exit after 30 seconds, call security].

`thanks in advance`

### Notes:

- `hello` and `thanks in advance` means process initiation and running while `goodbye` could be process termination
- I have no idea what will such a programming language be might be used for → humanoid robots comes to me in mind though.

### My question

Was there an attempt to create a programming language aimed for maximal abstraction?

Comment: How does this hypothetical language know how to open a shop, turn on an air conditioner, or what an opening day is? Are those all black boxes built into the language?

Comment: You might want to read some about [Moravec's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moravec%27s_paradox).

Comment: Your example looks very much like a Domain Specific Language (DSL). As the name suggests they are custom tailored for a specific domain and specific users.

Comment: @AaronRotenberg I guess by some "type" (?) of AI coded in the program which is the language.

Comment: @Daniel I recognize your point but after Aarron's comment I think a maximal abstraction language could be global and not domain specific - an answer addressing both possible implementations could be very informative and very interesting for others and for myself to read.

Comment: The purpose of a programming language is to unambiguously communicate logical rules. This is actually not possible with natural language. Counterexample: lawyers. If it were possible to unambiguously express rules in natural language, lawyers wouldn't exist, since there would be no need to interpret the law. And, by the way: laws are not actually written in natural language, they are written in legalese which is a domain-specific language (aka "jargon") for writing laws.

Comment: By the way, there are at least three rules in your program that I find unclear, even if I use my non-artificial intelligence to try and Interpret them. Also, I'm pretty sure that it's illegal to just lock customers in if they don't manage to leave the store by 20:00, but that is precisely what your program is doing.

Comment: @JörgWMittag hello; about your first comment: I am not sure what you wrote is totally right --- for example, the Torah and the Quran are two examples of religious-legal books that contain the explicit declarations that they are written simply and justly for both speakers of their languages to understand.

Comment: @JörgWMittag about your second  comment: I changed the pseudocode and further changes could be done ("is animal a microanimal or a nonmicroanimal?) but the principal remains.

Comment: Coming back to your first comments, another possible reason for me not to agree: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/34296/is-there-a-logical-background-theory-to-explain-control-flow-similarity-in-vir

Comment: People are literally killing each other right now about the meaning of certain parts of the Quran, so that is a perfect example of why natural language is *not* suitable for unambiguously specifying rules and processes. And both Islam and Judaism have entire professions whose purpose is interpreting the words of the Quran and the Torah.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I don't about Islam and about all religions in the world but in Judaism, to this day there are Karaites that hold "maximal self-interpretation" principles in regards to scripture; a similar approach might have by taken by reformationist Christians in regards to the Christian bible. In other words; I think one shouldn't dismiss a grey zone in this context.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, not all programming languages are even good at "unambiguously communicating logical rules". Like C/C++ is full of `undefined behaviors`, which are by definition are ambiguous, and different implementations are basically allowed to handle them as they wish.

Comment: @user28434 That's not what _undefined behavior_ means in C/C++. It's closer to what _implementation-defined behavior_ means in C/C++. Regardless, there is still only one valid behavior according to the language spec as long as you only use the rigorously demarcated parts of the language for which this is guaranteed.